# print .docx file to physical printer by jacob (JAVA-COM Bridge) as Monochrome printing

Tags: java, printing, jacob

I want to print .docx file to a physical printer by jacob. And it's work as below.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jacob</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
public class JacobPrint {
    static void print( String filePath){// filePath="D:\\1.doc";
        ComThread.InitSTA();
        ActiveXComponent word=new ActiveXComponent("Word.Application");
        Dispatch doc=null;
        Dispatch.put(word, "Visible", new Variant(false));
        Dispatch docs=word.getProperty("Documents").toDispatch();
        doc=Dispatch.call(docs, "Open", filePath).toDispatch();

        try {
            Dispatch.call(doc, "PrintOut");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if(doc!=null){
                    Dispatch.call(doc, "Close",new Variant(0));
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            ComThread.Release();
        }
}
```

But it is color printing.
How do I control it to print in color or monochrome?

Thanks a lot!

I have reference to Microsoft's official documentation: [Printer.ColorMode property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.printer.colormode)

But it seems to only work in the Access app, not in Word.